# Frequent WiFi disconnects with my WiFi router

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, wi-fi

I recently purchased Wireless Router and When I connected Wirelessly through my mobile(Sony Xperia P, android ver: 2.3.7), keeps on connecting and disconnecting for every 2mins. Whereas from other mobile(Samsung Galaxy Y) its perfectly connecting w/o any issues. Can someone pls tell me how to resolve this issue?

## Router details:

D-Link, Model No: DIR-600L, H/W ver: B1, F/W Ver: 2.00

Comment: Have you tried switching from a mixed WPA2/WPA or only WPA2 setting to WPA-PSK on the router?

Comment: Yes, tried..No luck..:( Any problem with my older version of android? And also just beside to my router, DTH set top box is kept.. Any problem with this..?

Comment: The Xperia P is upgradable to Android 4.1, by the way. This might as well fix it. It'll at least be worth a try.

Comment: But I connected to many Routers outside thru my mobile wirelessly and did not face this issue..'Galaxy Y' mobile consistently connected to my router without any issue.. Can someone pls tell me what exactly the problem here?

Comment: Can you grab the relevant wifi logs with [CatLog](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat) and edit them into your question (if not too long) or create a pastie at pastebin.com and give us a link? That would boost the investigation possibilities...

Comment: Pasted @ http://pastebin.com/JnVj86f4. Please see them.

Comment: Above link does not have the logs with android device connect..Pasting the correct link, which has logs with device connect & disconnects.. http://pastebin.com/0yGyVRw6

Comment: As you said I grabbed the WiFi logs from CatLog android app & pasted @ http://pastebin.com/vHgZQc8R..Pls see them..

Comment: You have 21 of these *Wifi driver reports HUNG, reloading* events, seems like instable wifi driver to me. I'll suggest you upgrade your Xperia P to the latest available 4.1 software and check again if it fixes this problem for you. Maybe paying around with the router's wifi settings can help to prevent this bug too, but YMMV.

Comment: Seems my issue got resolved now.. I've checked the 'Avoid ARP attack' in Router's LAN Settings.. I don't know how it is related to the issue.. Anyways now the problem is solved w/o upgrading my mobile's android version..:)

Comment: I figured out the exact solution & not the above one(checking the 'Avoid ARP attack' in Router's LAN Settings).. Solution is  unchecking the option in my android mobile --> "Use wireless networks" in "Location & security settings"..

Comment: You can by the way answer your own question, too! THanks for sharing this helpful information :-)

Answer (score 1):

Problem was solved by unchecking the option in my android mobile --> "Use wireless networks" in "Location & security settings".